# Ajax success not appending in table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a technical issue regarding my university small project. The task the professor gave me is as follows.

We are suppose to have static table which contains for example 3 domain names to give more performance on the domain availability API.

```
--------------------------------------------------
|example1.com |  $9.99 / year  |  Select Button  |
--------------------------------------------------
|example2.net |  $12.99 / year |  Select Button  |
--------------------------------------------------
|example3.org |  $6.99 / year  |  Select Button  |
--------------------------------------------------
```

**What is required?**

When I click for example the "Select Button" it will send the "example1.com" to the API to check its availability then it success function returns either 1 or 0 (1 is available and 0 is not available).

**if it is 1 we need to change the "Select Button" to "Selected"**

```
--------------------------------------------------
|example1.com |  $9.99 / year  |  Selected       |
--------------------------------------------------
|example2.net |  $12.99 / year |  Select Button  |
--------------------------------------------------
|example3.org |  $6.99 / year  |  Select Button  |
--------------------------------------------------
```

**if it is 0 we need to change the "Select Button" to "Not Available "**

```
--------------------------------------------------
|example1.com |  $9.99 / year  |  Not Available  |
--------------------------------------------------
|example2.net |  $12.99 / year |  Select Button  |
--------------------------------------------------
|example3.org |  $6.99 / year  |  Select Button  |
--------------------------------------------------
```

**Same goes for the rest , after checking all domains we will end up with the final table like this one for example**

```
--------------------------------------------------
|example1.com |  $9.99 / year  |  Not Available  |
--------------------------------------------------
|example2.net |  $12.99 / year |  Selected       |
--------------------------------------------------
|example3.org |  $6.99 / year  |  Selected       |
--------------------------------------------------
```

**My files**

1. index.html
2. domainapi.php

**index.html**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="domain">example1.com</td>
            <td>$9.99 / year</td>
            <td class="changebtn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Select</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="domain">example2.net</td>
            <td>$12.99 / year</td>
            <td class="changebtn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Select</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="domain">example3.org</td>
            <td>$6.99 / year</td>
            <td class="changebtn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Select</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-primary', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var domain = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.domain').text();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async: true,
            url: "domainapi.php",
            //`enter code here`
            data: {
                domain: domain
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == 1) {
                    /* change "Select Button" to "Selected"*/
                } else {
                    /* change "Select Button" to "Not Available"*/
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**domainapi.php**

```
$domain = $_GET["domain"];
$checkdomain = "https://api.example.com/xml.response?&Domain=$domain";
$data = file_get_contents($checkdomain);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
if( ! $xml)
{echo "unable to load XML file";}
else
{
foreach ($xml->CommandResponse->DomainCheckResult as $result)  {
$checkavailablity =  $result["Available"];
$checkprice       =  $result["PremiumRegistrationPrice"];
if (($checkavailablity == "true") && ($checkprice == "0"))
{echo 1;}
/*Ajax success: function(data) will return 1 and then we decided in the above success function to change the "Select Button" to "Selected"*/
else {echo 0;}
/*Ajax success: function(data) will return 0 and then we decided in the above success function to change the "Select Button" to "Not Available"*/
}
}
```

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: of course yes, I did not want to post everything in the code knowing that everybody knows how to include jquery.min.js

Comment: Not everybody knows. ;-)

Comment: What's exactly your problem or question?

Comment: I cannot change the "select" button to this text "Selected" or "not available" as explained very well above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your API return correct values?

I'm not sure if it works.

```
var index = $('.btn-primary').index(this);
if (data == 1) {
    /* change "Select Button" to "Selected"*/
    $('.btn-primary:eq(' + index + ')').html('Selected');
} else {
    /* change "Select Button" to "Not Available"*/
    $('.btn-primary:eq(' + index + ')').html('Not Available');
}
```

Comment: yes of course my API works very well, I just did not post the real link cause its from university

Comment: If this is the right answer, then the question is totally inadequate. It doesn't show the code he used to change the select button, so how can anyone tell what he did wrong and how this fixes it?

Comment: He just wanted the jquery code to put in the ajax success function... it's ok, just remember that in real life the shortcuts you take in the University will be charge to your success. Make sure you understand what he did there...